# Grab Ember component's content in JS file

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Let's say I have an Ember component "blah" and I use it in my template like this

```
{{#blah}}
  some content
{{/blah}}
```

I know that "some content" will be rendered whenever there is {{yield}} in the component's hbs file. But is there a way to grab "some content" as a string in the component's js file? E.g.

```
App.BlahComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  render: function(buffer) {
    var someContent = ???
  }
});
```

**Update**

Just to clarify what I am trying to do. I'd like to create a List View component. Something like this

```
{{#list-view}}
  <div> html for list item </div>
  <div> html for form </div>
{{/list-view}}
```

List view renders multiple list items. When you click a list item, form is getting shown. Form is the same for all list items, but has binding to a current list item's model. The above html is part of a template, which is generated on the server and there might be multiple list views in the same template.
What I am trying to do is to get what's between {{#}}{{/}} tags in the component's render method, parse it and render the list view manually.

Comment: Explaining the final outcome that you expect makes it easier to find the correct answer.

Comment: Where is someContent coming from? Is it JSON, XML? The quantity and quality of answers you get holds a direct relationship to the quality of your questions.

Comment: Why do you need to parse `someContent`? You said that those are forms coming from a server, my guess is that you are already receiving HTML/DOM elements. Use JQuery to insert that to a `div`. I think its time for you to make a: http://emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

You can not get the text in a template, unless you want to hack your way through it.

Pass a property.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  someContent: function() {
    return 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.';
  }.property()
});    

<!-- in index template -->
{{#blah someContent=someContent}}
  {{someContent}}
{{/blah}}   

App.BlahComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  render: function(someContent) {
    var someContent = this.get('someContent');
  }
});
```

Comment: Not sure I understood your answer. Why would I need a property? I need to get the html content from between the {{#}}{{/}} tags.

Comment: I edited the answer, although the gist remains the same.

Comment: Sadly this won't work for me. Template in my case is auto generated on the server and "someContent" is part of it. Is there a way to " hack my way through it"?

Comment: That doesn't change anything, you are probably receiving this through a route that sets the model for a controller that in turn can pass properties to a template. http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/displaying-model-data/